# Implication between propositions vs implication between predicates

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Based on what I read, I know that an implication $p\rightarrow q$ between two propositions p and q means “if p then q”. Since p and q are propositions, why, given a domain $D$, I often see sentences like $\forall x(p(x)\rightarrow q(x))$, where p(x) and q(x) are predicates, and thus not propositions? Is it an abuse of notation to express the proposition $\forall x (q(x))$, where the domain is now {$x|x\in D$ and $p(x)$}?
Moreover, I know that $p\rightarrow q \equiv \neg q \rightarrow \neg p$. By analogy I suppose that $\forall x(p(x)\rightarrow q(x))$ is a synonym of $\forall x(q’(x)\rightarrow p’(x))$, where p’(x) means “p(x) is not true” and q’(x) means “q(x) is not true”. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be conflating propositional logic with predicate logic. These are two different logics with a different language.

In propositional logic, we have propositional variables $p, q, ..$ and connectives $\neg, \to, ...$ between them, and that's it. All the formulas of propositional logic are made up of only propositional variables and connectives. Propositional variables directly stand for propositions, so something like $p$ will evaluate as true or false.

**Predicate logic is a different language. Here we do *not* have propositional variables: Something like $p \to q$ is not a formula of predicate logic.**
Instead, we have predicate symbols, which express properties and relations between individuals. These predicate symbols are also often called $p, q, ...$, but **they do not stand for propositions**. Instead, they stand for properties which are then applied to individuals (written $p(x)$) to produce a proposition. For example, $\text{even}$ could a predicate that expresses the property that some number is even, and $\text{even}(x)$ is the proposition "$x$ is even", which evaluates as true or false. Predicates are not themselves propositions (something that has a truth value), but can be seen as functions where you put in an individual (or a tuple of individuals) and you get out a truth value, depending on whether that individual has the property expressed by the predicate/the individuals stand in the relation expressed by the predicate.

By the definition of formulas in predicate logic (a term is an expression which stands for an individual):

> If $p$ is an $n$-place predicate and $t_1, ..., t_n$ are terms, then $p(t_1, ..., t_n)$ is a formula.

**$p$ is a predicate. $p(x)$ is *not* a predicate, but a formula.** In predicate logic, any formula will evaluate as true or false, so given that $p(x)$ is a formula, $p(x)$ *is* a proposition -- more precisely an expression that expresses the proposition "$x$ has the property $p$" which evaluates to a truth value. In predicate logic, so-called *atomic* formulas of the form $p(x)$ or $r(x,y)$ (that is, a single predicate applied to individuals without connectives) take the place of propositional variables $p, q, ...$ in propositional logic.
Furthermore, we have that

> If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are formulas, then $\phi \to \psi$ is a formula

and

> If $\phi$ is a formula and $x$ is a variable, then $\forall x \phi$ is a formula.

So not only $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, but also $p(x) \to q(x)$ and $\forall x(p(x) \to q(x))$ are formulas/propositions.

(Sometimes a more fine-grained distinction is made between an *expression* (a string of symbols) that stands for something which will later evaluate to a truth value -- which is be what we called "formulas" here -- and a "proposition" in the narrower sense, which is the propositional *semantic content* that the expression stands for. But the term "proposition" is very often used to mean "a string of symbols that expresses a proposition, i.e. something that is true or false", so we can adapt that sloppy terminology here.)

Again: **Propositional logic and predicate logics are two different languages. A symbol *p* in propositional logic means something different than a symbol *p* in predicate logic.** In propositional logic, *p* is a propositional variable that stands for a proposition. In predicate logic, there are no propositional variables. Instead, *p* stands for a predicate, which produces a proposition when applied to an individual, $p(x)$.

---

If you want to define a notaton $p'$ to mean "$p$ is not the case", then yes, $p(x) \to q(x)$ would be equivalent to $q'(x) \to p'(x)$, and hence also $\forall x(p(x) \to q(x))$ is equivalent to $\forall x(q'(x) \to p'(x))$. **But there is no need to introduce a special notation that expresses the negation of each predication, because we already have a symbol that expresses exactly that**: $\neg$. By the definition of formulas of predicate logic,

> If $\phi$ is a formula, then $\neg \phi$ is a formula

-- and since by the first definition $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are formulas, so are $\neg p(x)$ and $\neg q(x)$, and we can simply write

$p(x) \to q(x)\\
\equiv \neg q(x) \to \neg p(x)$

and hence

$\forall x(p(x) \to q(x))\\
\equiv \forall x (\neg q(x) \to \neg p(x)).$

Note that $\neg$ is applied to the formula (the proposition) $p(x)$, not to the predicate $p$: The bracketing is $\neg(p(x))$. What we negate is the truth of the proposition "$x$ has the property $p$".

Comment: It’s very clear, except for the part where you say that a formula is (or could be seen as) a proposition. I knew that some formulas aren’t proposition, such as “x>2” and “x>1” because we don’t know who x is and thus I can’t say anything about their truth value. Only after a quantifier enters they assume a truth value, and thus they become propositions. So I can’t understand what can I say about the truth of the formula “x>2$\rightarrow$ x>1” if there is not any quantifier.

Comment: Good point, sometimes you want to be carful about that distinction. What you call a proposition as opposed to a formula with free variables is what I know as "sentence", whereas anything that is a formula would qualify as "proposition" in my terminology; but some people may want to call a closed formula "proposition" instead of "sentence", and the rest is then just "formula". Terminology differs between different textbooks, so if my usage of the word "proposition" is confusing, just go with the distinction you're used to.